# trying to get the day difference between the two different format dates giving decimal points

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I am trying to get the days difference between two different dates like in these formats 
`2019-12-12T17:57:48.188-08:00` and other one is `new Date()` using the below formula

```
(Math.floor(new Date().getTime() - new Date(2019-12-12T17:57:48.188-08:00).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)).toString()
```

but some how getting this value `0.15538604166666667`

Could any one please suggest me on how to get exact difference in days between these two dates.
many thanks.

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so the forumla used in the OP `(d1 - d2) / 8.64e7` is wrong where the range includes a daylight saving change. See [*this answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11252167/257182) for more accurate results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this code and make use of `ceil()` function.

```
let dated=(new Date().getTime() - new Date("2019-12-12T17:57:48.188-08:00").getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
dated=Math.ceil(dated);
```

**Output : 1**

Comment: Code–only answers aren't that helpful. A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.